# ServiceController starts Manual StartType only but not Automatic

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, windows-services

I have a service installed, and I am trying to start it with the code below:

```
ServiceController serviceController = new ServiceController("My.Service");
serviceController.Start();
```

Now if the Service is set with a StartType of "Manual", this works perfectly. However if the StartType is set to "Automatic", it does nothing. No errors, no exceptions, it just does not work.

How do I get around this?

Comment: @JohnD - nothing. I see events of me manually starting it, or an event when it's set to Manual and my Start() call works. I'm curious if I need to do something different for when it's set to Automatic StartType?

Comment: That's probably because it is already started.  Control Panel + Administrative Tools + Services to check the service state.

Comment: @Hans Passant - no, it has no started, hence my reason for the question.

Comment: Hm, did you check the app, security, and system logs?  Seems very strange nothing would have gotten logged.  I'm wondering if the user account does not have permission to start a service, or something like that.  Does the process start at all (even briefly)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the service can run in manual mode, consider the other controllable aspects of the service, such as the **account under which the service executes** (LocalSystem or some other account?).

Please set the account type to local service during edit of windows service as below:

```
    1.Right click ServiceProcessInstaller1 and go to the properties tab

        a.Change the account to "LocalService"

   2. Save and try it.
```

Hope this will help you........

Comment: this works, however I need it to work under a specific user, rather than LocalService, as it needs access to a MS SQL Database. Any other ideas?

Comment: @JustinN, I don't think running under LocalService causes any problem if you use SQL authentication instead of windows authentication inside your connection string in the app.config file.

Comment: @JustinN, If you use windows authentication in SQL server it will use the local system account in which the service is running. So try changing the LoginAccount of the service to LocalSystem and give your system login credentials there. This can be done easily after installation also from "control panel-> Administrative tools->services->yourService" properties->logon.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, as I was out of the office. I've just tried what you suggested and it actually works perfectly now. Thank you for your time and patience.